# Multiple sub domains in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So i have:

```
class MainSite
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank? || request.subdomain == 'www'
    request.subdomain.blank? || request.subdomain == 'limitless-tor-hello' && 'rocky-depths-buhbye'
  end
end
```

But routing only works for limitless and not rocky.. Is it possible to have both of them work? I tried using the && operator which obviously didn't work.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MainSite
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank? || request.subdomain == 'www'
    request.subdomain.blank? || 
        request.subdomain == 'limitless-tor-hello' ||
        request.subdomain == 'rocky-depths-buhbye'
  end
end
```